# How to play it safe in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I’m a beginner in Fortnite and want to play it safe. How do you decide where to land such that there are not many players around. I have won a few games this way by waiting till everyone eliminated themselves. It doesn’t always work. I know it is not the best technique, but for now, it is the only way that works for my skill level. Is there any way to win without being in many fights with other players?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations which may cause it to be closed. If you believe this can be answered mainly with facts and not opinions, you can clarify that in your question body.

Answer (score 1):

Normally around the coast is fairly safe, but you need to find a spot that's quiet but still has a decent amount of equipment for you to get armed up quickly. And ideally where you can easily find a vehicle too, in case the storm circle ends up far away so you've got transport to save yourself. Some suggestions

- the house on the coast south of Chonkers Speedway: there's up to five chests there and six slurp barrels for shields (dig through the floor in the garage). There are two road cars there and you can head north to Chonkers to grab a car with off-road tyres if you need it
- either the house on the hill above Camp Cuddle - up to four chests inside (first one at the very top in the roof) and two just outside, and if someone else lands there you can flee down the hill
- or the garage just west of Camp Cuddle - less equipment but still a decent amount of potential shields and cars to get away in
- the dock on the coast north of Logjam; again 4+ chests
- or any of the islands on the far east of the map, which are normally fairly quiet. The one north of the bay though, north east of the Ruins, probably has most stuff.

But you're going to have to learn to fight. Waiting until everyone else has wiped each other out won't work in general, because

- when you kill someone you get all of their ammo, building materials and the pick of their equipment, so if you end up fighting someone who's been killing other people at the end you'll be heavily outgunned. Yes, they'll be weaker too if you catch them just after a fight but they can heal up pretty quickly so it's only a small window of opportunity.
- as the storm circles get smaller you often end up stumbling on others as you get into the circle, so you'll end up in combat whether you like it or not just to keep safe.

Try landing at Logjam for a few games. It's moderately popular (often 4-5 others will land there too): as long as you can find a chest and grab a weapon quickly you'll have a fighting chance, and there are plenty of chests around once you've learned where. Work out which weapons work well for you at what ranges, and you'll die a few times, but you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: if i may suggest, i would swap the positions of your points (e.g. do "you're going to have to learn to fight" before the location-centric advice) since Fortnite seasons and updates are constantly changing the map, adding, changing, or removing areas as promotions and the like are started and ended (like what happened recently with Tilted Towers).